# woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook not working properly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce_before_calculate_totals for adding extra price in woocommerce. If you add a product in cart and selected the price, the total price is correct in the checkout, but if the customer create his account in same process and checkout then the price is added twice after proced payment. This is my code

```
function calculate_gift_wrap_fee( $cart_object ) {
$additionalPrice = 100;
foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
if( isset( $value["gift_wrap_fee"] ) ) {
$orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );
$value['data']->price = ( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice );
        } 

}

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If customer choose `Create Account` option at the time checkout, woocommerce calls `calculate_totals()` second time ( after customer account registered and auto logged them ) in order to recalculate cart totals to reveal any role-based discounts that were unavailable before registering.

So what you can do is check for `"reload_checkout"` session which will be set before calling `calculate_totals()` second time.

So update your `calculate_gift_wrap_fee` like this

```
function calculate_gift_wrap_fee( $cart_object ) {  
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {
        /* Gift wrap price */
        $additionalPrice = 100;
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            if( isset( $value["gift_wrap_fee"] ) ) {
                $orgPrice = floatval( $value['data']->price );
                $value['data']->price = ( $orgPrice + $additionalPrice );
            }
        }   
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_gift_wrap_fee', 99 );
```

Comment: Yes it is now working, however i am testing, if is there any issue i will contact you. Thank you.